# How can I get the file creation date using URL resourceValues method in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsfilemanager, swift3

Thanks to a variety of helpful posts in this forum, I have some code that works for obtaining the Creation Date of a single user-selected NSURL.  However, I cannot get the code to work for either a hard-coded NSURL, nor within a loop through an NSFileManager enumerator.

I am not a professional programmer; I make apps that are tools for office.  My ultimate goal is to simply sort an Array of NSURL objects based on Creation Date.

The code I am using is below, which functions just fine as is, but if I try to use the commented line to evaluate a specific PDF file, I get the following error:

[image]

I get the exact same error when I try to add this code to a loop of NSURL objects procured via the NSFileManager Enumerator.

I cannot figure out how to use the error instruction to solve the problem.  If anyone can assist, that would be tremendous.  Thank you.

```
let chosenURL = NSOpenPanel().selectFile

    //let chosenURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "/Users/craigsmith/Desktop/PDFRotator Introduction.pdf")

    do
    {
        var cr:AnyObject?
        try chosenURL?.getResourceValue(&cr, forKey: URLResourceKey.creationDateKey)

        if (cr != nil)
        {
            if let createDate = cr as? NSDate
            {
                print("Seems to be a date: \(createDate)")

                let theComparison = createDate.compare(NSDate() as Date)

                print("Result of Comparison: \(theComparison)")  // Useless

                let interval = createDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

                print("Interval: \(interval)")

                if interval < (60*60*24*7*(-1))
                {
                    print("More than a week ago")

                }
                else
                {
                    print("Less than a week ago")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Not a Date")
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can extend URL as follow:

```
extension URL {
    /// The time at which the resource was created.
    /// This key corresponds to an Date value, or nil if the volume doesn't support creation dates.
    /// A resource’s creationDateKey value should be less than or equal to the resource’s contentModificationDateKey and contentAccessDateKey values. Otherwise, the file system may change the creationDateKey to the lesser of those values.
    var creation: Date? {
        get {
            return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]))?.creationDate
        }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.creationDate = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    }
    /// The time at which the resource was most recently modified.
    /// This key corresponds to an Date value, or nil if the volume doesn't support modification dates.
    var contentModification: Date? {
        get {
            return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey]))?.contentModificationDate
        }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.contentModificationDate = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    }
    /// The time at which the resource was most recently accessed.
    /// This key corresponds to an Date value, or nil if the volume doesn't support access dates.
    ///  When you set the contentAccessDateKey for a resource, also set contentModificationDateKey in the same call to the setResourceValues(_:) method. Otherwise, the file system may set the contentAccessDateKey value to the current contentModificationDateKey value.
    var contentAccess: Date? {
        get {
            return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentAccessDateKey]))?.contentAccessDate
        }
        // Beginning in macOS 10.13, iOS 11, watchOS 4, tvOS 11, and later, contentAccessDateKey is read-write. Attempts to set a value for this file resource property on earlier systems are ignored.
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.contentAccessDate = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
print(yourURL.creationDate)
```

Comment: That works beautifully, but the code seems so similar to what @OOPer posted, that I am still foggy on why this particular permutation functions, and the others (including mine) do not.

Comment: @ Leo Dabus - Any idea why your suggestion works on the Simulator but on the Device (iPhone XS) I get date, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000?  `let homeDirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()) if let creationDate = (try? homeDirURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]))?.creationDate{ print("CreationDate: \(creationDate)") // prints 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000}`

Comment: for iOS you should use documentDirectory not the user directory

Comment: In iOS the app is always sandboxed. Every time you run the app it will be in a different folder. So even if it had a valid date it wouldn't be what you are looking for. It would be practically the same as getting Date() when the app starts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Does your last statement refers to the `documentDirectory`?

Comment: @fs_tigre in iOS `URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())` points to the location of the bundle. It is where your documentDirectory is located (something like file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBD3746E-2530-4A82-AAA4-B3FFC329600D/) the last path component will change every time you launch the app (this is called sandbox). This is the directory you are trying to get the creation date which doesn't make any sense. You need to get its subdirectory Documents creation date.

Comment: `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.creation`

Comment: Ah got it, I thought you were saying that even if I get the `documentDirectory` it would change. I'm now using `let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first` Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @fs_tigre you are welcome. Note that this property is read-write. Check my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

According to the header doc of `URL` and `URLResourceValues`, you may need to write something like this:

(This code is assuming `chosenURL` is of type `URL?`.)

```
do {
    if
        let resValues = try chosenURL?.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]),
        let createDate = resValues.creationDate
    {
        //Use createDate here...
    }
} catch {
    //...
}
```

(If your `chosenURL` is of type `NSURL?`, try this code.)

```
do {
    if
        let resValues = try (chosenURL as URL?)?.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]),
        let createDate = resValues.creationDate
    {
        //Use createDate here...
        print(createDate)
    }
} catch {
    //...
}
```

I recommend you to use `URL` rather than `NSURL`, as far as you can.

Comment: Thank you, but the compiler complains that `Value of type [URLResourceKey:Any] has no member 'creationDate'` which seems crazy to me.

Comment: @CraigSmith, sorry, I was missing you are designating `NSURL` in the title and the comment, and my code is assuming `chosenURL` is of type `URL?`. It actually compiles without error in my Xcode 8 (8A218a) when I declare `chosenURL` as `URL?`. Please try.

Comment: this URL v NSURL stuff is crazy.  You are correct that your code does indeed function with a single URL or NSURL, however, when I try to use it inside of the NSFileManager derived Enumerator (which I believe is NSURL), the compiler complains `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, no URLResourceValues.`  Same error with either permutation, in fact, Xcode (8) prompts code corrections in both scenarios to the same error.  It is maddening to me.

Answer (score 2):

in swift 5 I use the following code:

```
let attributes = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: item.path)
let creationDate = attributes[.creationDate] as! Date
```

sort array with the following code

```
fileArray = fileArray.sorted(by: {
        $0.creationDate.compare($1.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
    })
```

more about FileAttributeKey here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributekey

Comment: Date conforms to Comparable protocol since Swift 3

Comment: This does the same as above but shorter `fileArray == fileArray.sorted{$0.creation! > $1.creation!}`. Sometimes though, some items are not in correct order; Do you guys know how to make it more stable?