# How to get the Documents folder creation date in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a production ready app where I want to present a view to only existing users but I don't currently have anything saved that could help me determine whether it's a new install or an update. I could do what's suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899503/check-if-my-ios-application-is-updated) thread but again, this wouldn't work in my case since I already have the app in production. The only possible option that I can think of is using the creation date of the `Documents` folder.

How can I get the date of when the `Documents` folder was created in iOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501096/2303865

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right thread. The one thing missing in that thread to fully answer my question is the URL to the documents directory. `let homeDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384443/2303865